# ngClass for multiple css styles condition

Tags: angular

**HTML**

```
    <span [ngClass]="{
                       'fas fa-star' : isSelected,
                       'far fa-star' : !isSelected
                     }"
          (click)="OnClick()">
    </span>
```

**typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-one-component',
  templateUrl: './one-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one-component.component.css']
})
export class OneComponentComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() isSelected : boolean;
@Output() change = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  OnClick(){
    this.isSelected= !this.isSelected;
    this.change.emit(this.isSelected);
  }

}
```

while clicking icon partial class were loaded like fas or far after space no class was added.

Comment: Interesting, seems like a bug, the common thing disappears in such expressions. The same expression work fine, if all the class name are unique. May be you have to change it like the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<span class="fa-star" [ngClass]="{
                   'fas' : isSelected,
                   'far' : !isSelected
                 }"
      (click)="OnClick()">
</span>
```

or

```
<span class="" [ngClass]="{
                   'fas' : isSelected,
                   'far' : !isSelected,
                   'fa-star' : true
                 }"
      (click)="OnClick()">
</span>
```

Class binding can be done as above.

Answer (score 1):

If you’ll have the class “fa-star” in both scenarios, you can just do something like this:

```
<span [ngClass]=“{‘fa-star’:true, ‘fas’: isSelected, ‘far’: !isSelected}”></span>
```